# Google Play services is not available. This application will close

Tags: android, sdk, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I'm quite new to android developement and I'm trying to run the [Google Plus SDK sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android) android sample project from GitHub using Android Studio. I can able to run the app successfully in the AVD kitkat/lollipop device. But after opening the app if I select the checkbox for "Request server with auth code?" it display this,

> Error: the value of `WEB_CLIENT_ID` or `SERVER_BASE_URL` is not set
>   correctly. This will cause error when requesting with server auth
>   code.

[image: G+ sample app signin error]

<sup>Screenshot - Click to enlarge</sup>

I've solved this error now see my answer. However I couldn't signin with google plus button.

UPDATE:

If I try running the same project in my mobile(physical device) running Lollipop 5.0.1 connected via usb the same error as above occurs(same as on AVD) and If I click "Sign in" button it displays to Choose an account popup. If I select my email and press ok. I have another error message displaying,

> Google Play services is not available. This application will close.

But all the play services apps including Google+ app is installed on my phone and none of them are disabled. How can I solve this error and am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I managed to fix this situation by following tutorial in this link (first 2 steps): http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1: Error: the value of WEB_CLIENT_ID or SERVER_BASE_URL is not set correctly**

Open `MainActivity.java` and set the server base url and the client id of your web application token variable for your token exchange server that you created in the Google developer console,

```
// Client ID for a web server that will receive the auth code and exchange it for a
// refresh token if offline access is requested.
private static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";

// Base URL for your token exchange server, no trailing slash.
private static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://yourtokenexchangeserver.com";
```

**Problem 2: Google Play services is not available. This application will close.**

You have to create a Signing certificate fingerprint(SHA1) using the keytool in the terminal app and try running the app. More on [this link.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api)